# JQuery not running sequentially to fade out box shadow

Tags: jquery, css

For some reason I cannot make jQuery run things sequentially.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Az9E2/

I would like to click a button, and have the following functions enacted sequentially:

1. Give `focus` to the textarea
2. Add a `box-shadow` to textarea
3. Delay for `100ms`
4. Add a `transition` class to the textarea
5. Remove the `box-shadow` and watch it `fade out` nicely

However, when I do it, it does everything an once, and so the `box-shadow` never appears.

Or, if I remove the final stage, then the box shadow `fades in`, meaning that (4) is happening BEFORE (2).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

source: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

---

The other points you mention of course all happen (*to the eye*) at once, because there is no delay preventing it.

---

try: http://jsfiddle.net/JH4fM/2/

```
$('#change').on('click', function () {
  var $el = $(".snapp_view_ask_question_textarea");

  $el.focus().css("box-shadow", "rgba(139, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 30px 2px");
  setTimeout(function () {
    $el.css("box-shadow", "");
  }, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ChangeStory(){

 $(".snapp_view_ask_question_textarea").focus().css("box-shadow", "rgba(139, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 30px 2px").addClass("textarea_transition");
 setTimeout(function(){$(".snapp_view_ask_question_textarea").css("box-shadow", "");}, 400);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build something using jquery's `delay` function.

You can find the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Az9E2/9/)